# squid transparent proxy (intercept) + router

Tags: proxy, router, transparent, squid

there is already a configured transparent proxy squid-3.5.27, there is an EdgeOSEdgeRouter router

I want to make a circuit

all computers on the network -> router -> squid

squid - 109.0.0.110
router - 109.0.0.1
test Windows - 109.0.0.8

configuration squid.conf, version - squid-3.5.27

```
# You should use the same dns resolver on squid and all clients
dns_nameservers 127.0.0.1

# acls
acl localnet src 109.0.0.0/24        # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.1.0/24 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.10.0/24        # RFC1918 possible internal network

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

acl blocked_http dstdomain "/etc/squid/blocked_sites.txt"

# http access
http_access deny !Safe_ports

http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

http_access deny blocked_http

http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all

http_port 3128 intercept
https_port 3129 intercept  ssl-bump connection-auth=off cert=/etc/squid/squidCA.pem
http_port 3130

always_direct allow all
sslproxy_cert_error allow all
sslproxy_flags DONT_VERIFY_PEER

acl blocked ssl::server_name "/etc/squid/blocked_https.txt"
acl whitelist src "/etc/squid/whitelist_ip.txt"
ssl_bump splice whitelist
acl step1 at_step SslBump1
ssl_bump peek step1

ssl_bump terminate blocked
ssl_bump splice all

sslcrtd_program /opt/source/squid-3.5.27/src/ssl/ssl_crtd -s /var/lib/ssl_db -M 4MB
sslcrtd_children 8 startup=1 idle=1

acl YOUTUBE ssl::server_name .googlevideo.com
delay_pools 1
delay_class 1 2
delay_parameters 1 -1/-1 5120/5120
delay_access 1 allow YOUTUBE

coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320
cache_dir aufs /var/spool/squid 20000 49 256
maximum_object_size 61440 KB
minimum_object_size 3 KB

cache_swap_low 90
cache_swap_high 95
maximum_object_size_in_memory 512 KB
memory_replacement_policy lru
logfile_rotate 4
```

try this [doc](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TransparentProxy-6.html)

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 ! -s 109.0.0.110 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 109.0.0.110:3128
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 109.0.0.8/32 -d 109.0.0.110/32 -j SNAT --to 109.0.0.1
iptables -A FORWARD -s 109.0.0.8/32 -d 109.0.0.110/32 -i eth0 -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 3128 -j ACCEPT
```

prescribed iptables

I try to open a site on a test Windows (109.0.0.8) - access is denied, on Windows the gateway is 109.0.0.1, in the logs on squid

```
1546203601.533      0 109.0.0.110 TCP_MISS/403 4857 GET http://myip.ru/ - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1546203601.533      1 109.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/403 4977 GET http://myip.ru/ - ORIGINAL_DST/109.0.0.110 text/html
```

tcpdump squid server

```
11:00:57.141246 IP 109.0.0.8.54026 > myip.ru.http: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 1, win 2087, length 0
11:00:57.141570 IP 109.0.0.8.54030 > myip.ru.http: Flags [S], seq 1736419147, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
11:00:57.141971 IP myip.ru.http > 109.0.0.8.54026: Flags [.], ack 2, win 58, length 0
11:00:57.142115 IP myip.ru.http > 109.0.0.8.54026: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 2, win 58, length 0
11:00:57.142304 IP myip.ru.http > 109.0.0.8.54030: Flags [S.], seq 4065681746, ack 1736419148, win 29200, options [mss 1452,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 9], length 0
11:00:57.142363 IP 109.0.0.8.54026 > myip.ru.http: Flags [.], ack 2, win 2087, length 0
11:00:57.142505 IP 109.0.0.8.54030 > myip.ru.http: Flags [.], ack 1, win 260, length 0
11:00:57.144743 IP 109.0.0.8.54025 > myip.ru.http: Flags [P.], seq 2136:2856, ack 23054, win 2087, length 720: HTTP: GET / HTTP/1.1
11:00:57.146027 IP myip.ru.http > 109.0.0.8.54025: Flags [P.], seq 23054:23572, ack 2856, win 69, length 518: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

tell me what could be the problem, I will be grateful for any help?

**Update**

when you open a site on http by Windows, it is issued - 403, by https - an invalid certificate, the proxy server certificate is substituted in the browser, what am I doing wrong?

**Update 2**

when adding rules on a router

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i eth0 -s 109.0.0.8 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 109.0.0.110:3128
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i eth0 -s 109.0.0.8 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 109.0.0.110:3129
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 109.0.0.8 -d 109.0.0.110 -j SNAT --to 109.0.0.1
```

proxy server rules

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [314:20555]
:INPUT ACCEPT [313:20511]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [844:60999]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [2:130]
-A PREROUTING -s 109.0.0.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3129
-A PREROUTING -s 109.0.0.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
-A PREROUTING -s 192.168.10.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3129
-A PREROUTING -s 192.168.10.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
-A PREROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3129
-A PREROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
-A POSTROUTING -s 109.0.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 109.0.0.110
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.10.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 109.0.0.110
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 109.0.0.110
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [340:18626]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1809:273786]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 109.0.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.10.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j LOG
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 3128:3130 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -s 109.0.0.0/24 -p udp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j DROP
COMMIT
```

when you open a site on Windows on http, in cache.log

```
kid1| WARNING: Forwarding loop detected for:
GET / HTTP/1.1^M
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1^M
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36^M
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8^M
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate^M
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7^M
Via: 1.1 proxy.server (squid/3.5.27)^M
X-Forwarded-For: 109.0.0.1^M
Cache-Control: max-age=259200^M
Connection: keep-alive^M
Host: myip.ru^M
^M
kid1| WARNING: Forwarding loop detected for:
GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1^M
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36^M
Accept: image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8^M
Referer: http://myip.ru/^M
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate^M
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7^M
Via: 1.1 proxy.server (squid/3.5.27)^M
X-Forwarded-For: 109.0.0.1^M
Cache-Control: max-age=259200^M
Connection: keep-alive^M
Host: myip.ru^M
```

in access.log

```
1546711344.892      0 109.0.0.110 TCP_MISS/403 4514 GET http://myip.ru/ - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1546711344.893      0 109.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/403 4634 GET http://myip.ru/ - ORIGINAL_DST/109.0.0.110 text/html
1546711344.913      0 109.0.0.110 TCP_MISS/403 4479 GET http://myip.ru/favicon.ico - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1546711344.913      0 109.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/403 4599 GET http://myip.ru/favicon.ico - ORIGINAL_DST/109.0.0.110 text/html
```

> WARNING: Forwarding loop detected for

how to fix it, any help ?

Comment: if I prescribe a gateway on Windows - 109.0.0.110, then everything works without firewall rules, but you need to configure it to work through a router - 109.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Don't use DNAT and change destination IP! Forward your traffic to the Squid machine as it was generated on the client machine by changing the IP routing table. See https://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Intercept/IptablesPolicyRoute

I had the same problem which has been solved by this approach.